# If $\int_Afdx = \int_Agdx$ for every Lebesgue measurable set $A$ is it then true that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every x?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f, g$ be continuous functions in a measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{F}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I do know a proof that if $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}:\int_Afdx = \int_Agdx$ then $f = g$ $\mu$-a.e.  What I am wondering is that under which assumptions could we conclude that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in X$. Or does there exists an easy counterexample for this?

Comment: *Hint:* If two *continuous* functions $f, g$ are not identical then their difference is non-zero on some interval.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, I see. Suppose that $f(x)\neq g(x)$ for some $x\in X$. By continuity of $f$, there exists a neighborhood $B(x,r)$ such that $g(a)\neq f(x)$ for every $a\in B(x,r)$. Integrating over this neighbourhood shows that $\int_{B(x,r)}f - gdx \neq 0$. Hence $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X$.